# Circular progress button based on hold (flutter)

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to make a button where when user hold it, there will be a progress, but if the user unpress the button before it finish, the progress will decrease. somthing like the one on the picture[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As said by Arnold Parge, you can use the [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) and listen to `onTapDown` and `onTapUp`. To create your desired LoadingButton, you can use the following Widget Structure:

```
- GetureDetector
  - Stack
    - CircularProgressIndicator // background circle
    - CircularProgressIndicator // foreground circle
    - Icon
```

To create the animation, you can add an [AnimationController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) and bind the value of the foreground `CircularProgressIndicator` to `AnimationController.value`. Now you'll just have to the add the two listeners to to the `GestureDetector`:

- `onTapDown`: When tapping on the button, the animation should start. Therefore we call `AnimationController.forward()`
- `onTapUp`: When releasing the press, we want to check if the animation is already finished. We can use [AnimationController.status](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationStatus-class.html) to check the status. If it is `AnimationStatus.forward` it is still running. Hence we want to reverse the animation with calling `AnimationController.reverse()`.

Here is the resulting button:

[image: Button Animation]

And the **complete** source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: LoadingButton()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoadingButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  LoadingButtonState createState() => LoadingButtonState();
}

class LoadingButtonState extends State<LoadingButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) => controller.forward(),
      onTapUp: (_) {
        if (controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward) {
          controller.reverse();
        }
      },
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          CircularProgressIndicator(
            value: 1.0,
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.grey),
          ),
          CircularProgressIndicator(
            value: controller.value,
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
          ),
          Icon(Icons.add)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: might be a bit late, but how do i trigger it once the progress is finish during tap down? because right now i can trigger it only if the user tap up the button.

Comment: @ali you can also add a conditional to the `onTapDown` handler. If I didn't got your question right, would you mind specifying what you exactly need? :)

Comment: As Ali asked, can anyone drop a hint on how to fire off come code once the CircularProgressIndicator has filled and the animation has completed? Much appreciated! I added the following to onTapDown:

 if(controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
            setState(() {
              _theValue = "FINISHED";
            });
        }

Won't fire.

Comment: Never mind, I placed a variable in Widget Build and that catches it :)

String _theValue = controller.value.toString();

Answer (score 2):

Use [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html).

Start the progress in `onTapDown` and reverse the progress in `onTapUp` if the progress is not complete or whatever your conditions are.