# Auto increment a value as the button is pressed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a calculation app where a variable is increased/decreased by a plus button and a minus button. I would like to implement a continuous increment/decrement when long-pressing (holding) the plus or minus button.
How can this be done with dart/flutter?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424764/circular-progress-button-based-on-hold-flutter

Comment: No not really, I need a value to increase/decrease, not an animation change.

Comment: so instead of animation just update the value on the event.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see any solution in that example. What part of your example is similar to an autoincrement of a variable when long-press a button? Maybe my question is unclear. I probably need to rephrase my question.

Comment: Probably you can use GestureDetector onTapDown and onTapUp. Start Timer.periodic/CountDownTimer and increase the value when onTapDown. Stop when onTapUp.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just a quick sample code.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: NewCode(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class NewCode extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewCodeState createState() => _NewCodeState();
}

class _NewCodeState extends State<NewCode> {
  Timer timer;
  var value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              'value $value',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
            )),
          ),
          onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
            print('down');
            timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 500), (t) {
              setState(() {
                value++;
              });
              print('value $value');
            });
          },
          onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
            print('up');
            timer.cancel();
          },
          onTapCancel: () {
            print('cancel');
            timer.cancel();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But how do we say 'onTapUp'  for  web?

Comment: 'onTapUp'  is working. it is printing 'Up'. But timer.cancel() is not working

Answer (score 0):

For those who have problems with above answer's code where timer.cancel() does not work. Depending on what state management method you are using (in my case Riverpod 2.0), a widget rebuild will cause the assigned timer variable to be null again, thus, cancel() method will not work (since it is null then). The initial timer will continue to run since the reference gets lost.

Comment: Don’t refer to other answers in your answer. If you want to comment on an answer use the comment section (which will be available after gaining the rights for it)