# Customized Raw Material Button - Flutter

Tags: flutter, button, widget

I want to add a property to a RawMaterialButton class, such that when I keep the button pressed, it increases the value of a variable continuously. Just like when we press a mobile camera's capture button for a long time it clicks multiple captures until we leave the button. Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a GestureDetector with a timer. When the onTapDown event fires start the timer. When the onTapUp event fires stop the timer. Use a Timer.periodic() timer to increment the variable repeatedly. There are multiple questions that are related to this, for example: [auto-increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417182/auto-increment-a-value-as-the-button-is-pressed-in-flutter), [button-on-hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424764/circular-progress-button-based-on-hold-flutter), and others. Here are my onTapDown and onTapUp methods from a widget that I built to do this (I wanted an initial delay before the action was repeated, hence the check of timer.tick):

```
Timer _timer;
.
.
.
void _onTapDown() {
  <on pressed action>
  _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 200), (timer) {
    if (timer.tick < 3) {
      return;
    }
    if (widget == null) {
      timer.cancel();
      return;
    }
    <on pressed action>
  });
}

void _onTapUp() {
  if (_timer == null) {
    return;
  }
  _timer.cancel();
}
```