# Flutter Progress Text Button

Tags: flutter, widget

Looking for a widget similar to the answer by NiklasPor in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424764/circular-progress-button-based-on-hold-flutter). The whole idea fits my needs - have a button that changes border drawn based on how long the button is held. The problem is that the `CircularProgressIndicator` is used here. I need on hold feature and border drawing to be compatible with the `TextButton` widget, for example. Basically, I want a `TextButton` to execute a function if it is held long enough. Any ideas how to start with this? I am thinking of also using the `GestureDetector` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this package: [square_percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/square_percent_indicater)

Comment: No, I have not. It looks like something that could work. I will try this out tonight.